# Explain using statement in C# code in middle of code... (not in header as loading libraries)

Tags: c#, using

Please, can anyone explain to me statement in c# "using". I know that I use it at header of program to load basic libraries such as using System.Text;. But is not clear to me, What is the difference between:

```
using (var font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f)) 
{
    byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
}
```

and:

```
using var font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);
byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
```

And Yes, I read the manuals for C#, But i don´t understand this in practical way.

Comment: `using` in this is different from the `using` for namespaces. Namespace `using` is a `using directive`, where in code its `using statement`. A using statement in code is using an object that inherits from `IDisposable`, which means its reclaimed by the garbage collector (aka `disposed`) right after the brackets end. Your second example is new syntactical sugar added in C# 8.0. Its fundamentally the same as your first example, just a different way of writing it. The only difference is it gets disposed when the surrounding block closes rather than the brackets attached to it

Comment: Have a look https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#using-declarations

Comment: If I understand, it is good for memory saving. Once if program finish task in brackets garbage collector clear that from variable. And variable is assigned when is not used, It is only assigned when code running in brackets.

Comment: @Sahasrar there are various things that might need to be disposed of, such as an SQL connection, file lock etc. that .NET isn't managing. Memory usage is one possibility.

Comment: Yeah, when I was trying to work with XML, it was very unpleasant to load whole XML(up to 35MB) and do some stuff with it and holding in at memory. I was trying use GC.Collect at bottom of code, but it is not working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`using` is used in conjunction with types that implement the `IDisposable` interface.

It ensures that when the object is out of scope, the `Dispose` method is called (as defined in `IDisposable`) and is often used to dispose of unmanaged resources.

Your first example is a traditional using block, where the object scope is defined by the following {}.

Your second is a new using statement, introduced in C#8, where the scope is the enclosing block, as with other local variables.

It is roughly equivalent to:

```
var font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);
byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
font1.Dispose();
```

But as pointed out by Casey, it actually ensures the object is disposed of, even if an exception is thrown inside the block i.e.

```
var font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);
try
{
    byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
}
finally
{
    if (font1 != null)
    {
        font1.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: almost! In your code, if there is any error thrown in `byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;`, then `font1.Dispose();` will never be called.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston yes, good point, and it also does a null check in the finally block.

Comment: In the finally part, you can just write `font1?.Dispose();`.

Answer (score 1):

There's multiple meanings of using in c#.

It can be used to import namespaces to a class, as you describe with the System.Text example. This is a [using directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive)

When you're using unmanaged resources in your code, like SQLConnection, streams etc they generally implements the [IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netframework-4.8) interface. When you consume a type implementing this interface you have to call the dispose method after you're done using this type.

To simplify usage of this pattern, especially when exceptions happens, C# introduced the using statement - it will automatically call dispose for you.

In C#8, a simplified syntax was introduced that doesn't require any curly braces.

You can find out more about using [here](https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2019/04/09/using/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

Comment: Fortunately, i ask this trivial question (for pros programators :D). So, using is equal to import in header like  C or Java. It is cool to call dispose to free memory after use.

Comment: In general, you do not have to do this kind of clean up. For managed code, the garbage collector will do it automatically for you. For unmanaged code, it's different though.